# Fetching JSON Data that doesn't have key in framework 7 v2

Tags: javascript, json, cordova, phonegap, html-framework-7

My JSON Data

```
[
  {
    "ID": 000,
    "pass_Word": "abc",       
  }
]
```

I want to get the value of **ID** from this JSON.

My Current Code:

```
var Data = {"User_ID" : login_id, "password" : password};
JSON.stringify(Data);
app.request.post('http://URL?type=json', Data , function (data) {           
  console.log(data.ID);
});
```

From the above code I am getting ***undefined*** in response.

Please help me out in this.

Comment: Use `data[0].ID` to access ID field. because in your api response return Array Object

Comment: Thanks for this. It worked successfully. Additionally, I have to first parse the JSON data that I am getting and then use data[0].ID